# knit raises error but html is rendered ok

Tags: r, r-markdown, shiny-server

Got a simple Rmarkdown on my server called `index.Rmd`, It's an Ubuntu server machine with latest Rstudio and shiny-server. When knitting using RStudio Server button "knit", everything goes fine. A window is opened with report.

Then users tried to access Report using browser and a message in red letters is shown:

```
An error has occurred. Check your logs or contact the app author for clarification.
```

Checked Shiny-server error log:

```
processing file: index.Rmd
Installing package into '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Installing package into '/usr/local/lib/R/site-library'
(as 'lib' is unspecified)
Warning in install.packages("BiocInstaller", repos = a["BioCsoft", "URL"]) :
  'lib = "/usr/local/lib/R/site-library"' is not writable
Quitting from lines 20-55 (index.Rmd)
Warning: Error in install.packages: unable to install packages
Stack trace (innermost first):
    135: install.packages
```

Packages mentioned in between lines 20-55 are magrittr, RDocumentation and tidyverse, so I opened a R terminal with putty against server and wrote:

```
install.packages(c("magrittr","RDocumentation","tidyverse"))
```

Installed ok. No error. Opened browser again. But same error appeared. So i installed packages again as root (to no avail).

Checked if HTML file is generated, and to my surprise, there's a html file called `index.html`.
if I point browser to `index.html`report is working ok and is redendered on browser.!!! It's a simple report with no interaction required, so I used Rmd files instead of Shiny files.
I have some other Rmd reports working ok located in other folders, so I'm sure my server is working ok.

As a workaround I've instructed users to open html instead of Rmd, but the point of having a Rmd file is to get updated report when data changed. Otherwise I'd used html in the first place.

can't understand what is happening. any suggestion?

Comment: Did you install the packages in question into the `/usr/local/lib/R/site-library` folder or in a different one?

Comment: Didn't choose a specific folder. Just issued install.packages.  the thing is annoying me is why other similar reports are working ok. Library is the same for all. For the same reason, if packages are not present on library why html report is ok?

Comment: @Forge, do you have `install.packages()` inside your *.Rmd files? It would be good idea to remove them and leave only library calls.

Comment: Could it be that the dynamic parts of the report were already created and stored by a previous session and the report included the "old" results? Anyway I would check if the missing packages are indeed present in said folder and if not install them into the folder.

Comment: Andrey , first I check if package is installed. if not, then I install it. But anyway it's not working